# How to insert data into databse using laravel and integrate with the android app

Tags: php, android, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

If it possible to develop the project using Laravel in android application, if there is a way to develop in Laravel please suggest me something to insert the data in database. I have tried in php it's working fine same thing I have done in laravel .

```
<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('dass') or die(mysql_error());
    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
    $password=$_REQUEST['password'];
    $mail=$_REQUEST['mail'];
    $q=mysql_query("select * from login1 where  email='".$mail."' ") or die(mysql_error());
    $n=mysql_fetch_row($q);
    if($n>0)
    {
        echo "The username name '.$name.' or mail '.$mail.' is already registered";
    }
    else
    {
        $insert=mysql_query("insert into `login1` (`name` ,`email`,`password`) values('".$name."','".$mail."','".$password."')") or die(mysql_error());
        if($insert)
        {
            echo "Values are registered successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Values are not registered";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Yes it's possible you need to create APIs(webservices) using laravel then you can call them from android app. Learn about json restful APIs you will get to know how useful it is.

Comment: I am new in laravel , please suggest me some website , how to insert delete and update using laravel through url..

Comment: that's what you will learn just google it out json restful web-services and then search how you can create them in laravel.

Comment: i have done, but im not getting exact solution for that because laravel technologies is not used by many peoples thats y im asking this query... some how please send me some websites..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in laravel, Models are used for database tables, and all the database manipulation for that table is done by the Models.

One model represents one table.

For the database connection, add your connection details in .env file located in root folder, or in config/database.php file.

The method for the insertion will be in controller class,

```
    public function store(Request $request){
       $model = new Model; // this model represent your database table, so you can name it according to your requirement.
       $model->name = $request->name;
       $model->password =$request->password;
       $model->mail = $request->mail;
       if($model->save()){
         echo "Succesfully added";
       }else{
         echo 'something went wrong';
       } 
    }
```

the database column names must be matched with the model properties.

Comment: all the API parameters are accessible using request object, then you can send the response accordingly.